When I compile rclcpp in the jazz version on Ubuntu 24.04, it prompts the following error
When I compile rclcpp in the jazz version on Ubuntu 24.04, it prompts the following error：
Starting >>> rclcpp
*--- stderr: rclcpp                   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/executor/__init__.py", line 91, in __call__
    rc = await self.task(*args, **kwargs)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/task/__init__.py", line 93, in __call__
    return await task_method(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_ros/task/ament_cmake/build.py", line 59, in build
    rc = await extension.build(
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_cmake/task/cmake/build.py", line 87, in build
    rc = await self._reconfigure(args, env)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_cmake/task/cmake/build.py", line 133, in _reconfigure
    buildfile = get_buildfile(cmake_cache)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_cmake/task/cmake/__init__.py", line 114, in get_buildfile
    if 'Visual Studio' in generator:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
---
Failed   <<< rclcpp [1.74s, exited with code 1]*

Has anyone encountered it before
